# Node.js request.post return undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, return, undefined

I'm trying to return the body of a post request of another site in node.js, but the function below doesn't return anything

```
  // returns "undefined"
  mysqlVerify = (socialclub_id, session_id) => {
      request({
          url: 'http://myapi.site/VerifyUser',
          method: 'post',
          form: {
            socialclub_id: socialclub_id,
            session_id: session_id
          }
      }, (error, response, body) => {
          if(error) {
              return false       // this isnt returning
          } else {
              console.log(response.statusCode, body)
              return body == "1" // this isnt returning
          }
      })
  }
```

The other site is receiving the post request, and I am also getting the right body back when I use `console.log`, but the return just doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `return` inside a callback to return a value when your function is called. You could pass `mysqlVerify` a callback (a function which is run once the result is determined) and call it once you get a response, like so:

```
mysqlVerify = (socialclub_id, session_id, callback) => {
    request({
        url: 'http://myapi.site/VerifyUser',
        method: 'post',
        form: {
            socialclub_id: socialclub_id,
            session_id: session_id
        }
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        if(error) {
            callback(false)       // call the function if false
        } else {
            console.log(response.statusCode, body)
            callback(body == "1") // call the function if condition met
        }
    });
}
```

The `callback` function can then do whatever you need with the result of `mysqlVerify`.